# Large PDF document cannot translate

Tags: python

am trying to translate the PDF document around 14MB file so am not able to translate that and once translate will be complete then need to store in to blob storage. Need a code for that anyone help me on that

Need a code for the large pdf documents need to translate and that it will store in azure blob.

Comment: Can you provide what you are doing and what errors you are getting? What translation library and service you are using? Provide your code and what errors you are getting please.

Comment: we cant help you fix your code but not write it for you